# Routes on React, TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of undefined(…)

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm trying basic stuff with ReactJS and I'm trying to understand how to work with **React-Router**

This is my code:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var Router = require('react-router').Router;
var Route = require('react-router').Route;

const Home = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (<h1>Welcome to the Home Page</h1>);
  }
});

ReactDOM.render((
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    </Router>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

I keep getting the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getCurrentLocation' of
>   undefined(…)

I'm using webpack to compile the jsx into js, what am I missing ? (btw no error from the webpack)

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the history definition for your Router try:

```
<Router history={hashHistory|browserHistory|createMemoryHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
</Router>
```

NB: You'll have to add the chosen history type to your imports with React router, so if you choose to add **browserHistory** your import would look something like this:

```
import { browserHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router'
           ^---added as a named import
```

---

*A brief explanation of the different options:*

[browserHistory](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory) : bases your path of the full url starting with the route '/'.  So if your SPA is at www.myapp.com, the root path will coorespond to `www.myapp.com/` by default.  So if you wanted a route to `www.myapp.com/blog`, you would need to define a router path of '`/blog`'.

[hashHistory](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#hashhistory): does the same thing but the root starts from the the first `#` character found in the url: `example.com/#/some/path` would correspond to: `/some/path`

[createMemoryHistory](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#creatememoryhistory): used for testing and for server rendering.  This option does not read from *or* manipulate the address bar.

Check out: [React Router Histories](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md) for more info

Comment: I tried to add another class named Testit, so the routes look like this now
`   <Router history={browserHistory}>
    <Route path="/" component={Home} />
    <Route path="/test" component={Testit} />
  </Router> ` when I go to http://localhost:3030/test
nothing is showing but when I go for `/` I can see Home component

what am I missing now ?
thanks a lot!

Comment: You should nest the `/test` path within the Home path route as follows: `<Router history={browserHistory}> <Route path="/" component={Home} > <Route path="/test" component={Testit} /></Route> </Router>`

Comment: I tried that now, and I'm getting 404 page
http://pastebin.com/Gsjy4TEs

Comment: This issue may help. https://github.com/ReactjsProgram/React-Fundamentals/issues/36