# React router not working - no errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';
var ReactRouter = require('react-router');
var Router  = ReactRouter.Router;
var Route = ReactRouter.Route;
var Navigation = ReactRouter.Navigation;

var StorePicker = React.createClass({
render : function() {
return (
  <form className="store-selector">
    <h2>Please Enter A Store</h2>
    </form>
)
}

});

var routes = (
<Router>
<Route path="/" component={StorePicker}/>
<Route path="store" component={App}/>
</Router>
)
export default routes;
```

---

I am trying to work with react router. This code is not working. It doesn't gives any errors. But it gives two warnings.

---

Warning: Failed prop type: The prop `history` is marked as required in `Router`, but its value is `undefined`.
    in Router

---

React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

Comment: The first warning is self-explanatory. The Router component requires a `history` prop and you haven't supplied one. Consult the documentation for the version of react-router you're using. The second warning can't be diagnosed without knowing where it's coming from. You're not calling `React.createElement` in the code above, so it must be somewhere else.

Comment: In response to the first warning: [check out this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41023726/2902660)

Comment: You have not imported app component but you have used in route.

Comment: @TusharKotlapure This isn't the whole code , App is in this code only. Sorry for not mentioning that :)

Answer (score 0):

**For the warning:**
*(Warning: Failed prop type: The prop history is marked as required in Router, but its value is undefined. in Router)*

You're missing the history definition for your Router try:

```
<Router history={hasHistory|browserHistory|createMemoryHistory}>
  <Route path="/" component={Home} />
</Router>
```

NB: You'll have to add the chosen history type to your imports with React router, so if you choose to add **browserHistory** your import would look something like this:

```
import { browserHistory, Router, Route } from 'react-router'
           ^---added as a named import
```

---

*A brief explanation of the different options:*

[browserHistory](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory) : bases your path of the full url starting with the route '/'.  So if your SPA is at [www.myapp.com](http://www.myapp.com), the root path will coorespond to `www.myapp.com/` by default.  So if you wanted a route to `www.myapp.com/blog`, you would need to define a router path of '`/blog`'.

[hasHistory](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#hashhistory): does the same thing but the root starts from the first `#` character found in the url: `example.com/#/some/path` would correspond to: `/some/path`

[createMemoryHistory](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#creatememoryhistory): used for testing and for server rendering.  This option does not read from *or* manipulate the address bar.

Check out: [React Router Histories](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md) for more info

Comment: This still works the same. It doesn't display "Please enter a store" at http://localhost:3000/. I entered browserHistory as prop and imported it.